# Docker - Auto reload de Spring boot no funciona en el contenedor

Tags: spring-boot, docker

Tengo un proyecto de `Maven` que lo cree usando [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/), armé un contenedor y este levanta la app sin problema, pero cuando hago un cambio en el código este no se ve reflejado si no reinicio el contenedor.

Este es mi `Dockerfile.dev`:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-jammy

WORKDIR /app

COPY .mvn/ .mvn
COPY mvnw ./
COPY pom-dev.xml ./pom.xml
COPY ./src ./src

CMD ["./mvnw", "spring-boot:run"]
```

Y por último mi `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  spring-rest-api-test:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    links: 
      - db 
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app/src
  db:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - "3307:3307"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password123
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
```

Salida en consola cuando arranca la app:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenté usar esto en `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <configuration>
        <excludeDevtools>false</excludeDevtools>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

pero no surte efecto.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando la app se ejecuta desde un contenero no se puede cambiar, está en modo producción.

Sólo se debería usar este modo para pruebas finales o para ejecutar la aplicación sirviendo a los clientes.

Para poner utilizar el auto reload, tienes que estar en modo desarrollo. Esto es, ejecutar la app con `mvn spring-boot:run` o similar.